# I would like to get all the JMS Keys and Values to be printed in a log file

Tags: groovy, soapui

Screenshot of the requirements:

[image]

I would like to use a groovy script to get the response JMS properties.

Is it possible to get it with `log.info` ?

I am expecting to print all the 23 JMS keys and values to an output file or log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `Groovy script` testStep you can get the SOAP testStep by it's name, and access the response to get all the response headers:

```
// get the response headers
def headers = testRunner.testCase.testSteps['Your SOAP Request testStep Name'].getTestRequest().getResponse().getResponseHeaders();
// iterate all keys and print the key and value
headers.getKeys().each{
    log.info it + headers.get(it,'default')
}
```

Comment: you're welcome, if the answer solve your problem think about accept it